# Twilio Using Rest API -without library

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to send a sms without using a library, as I can't add any DLL's to my project.

I've formatted the following url correctly from the API and I don't seem to get an SMS.

https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACd4311678edb1e37c3a67a86c5fc94593/SMS/Messages?from=+441183100455&to=+447792825508&body='Hello_World'

Comment: What does the response look like?

Comment: You may need to send a POST request instead of a HTTP GET request. In addition you need to Authenticate with your Account Sid and Auth Token.

Answer (score 0):

Ricky from Twilio here.

One quick way to generate an API request is to use the [API Explorer](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/developer-tools/api-explorer/message-create).

For example, the explorer would give you this code to show how to make an HTTP request using curl to the API:

```
curl -X POST 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/[AccountSid]/Messages.json' \
--data-urlencode 'To=555-555-5555'  \
--data-urlencode 'From=+15555551234'  \
--data-urlencode 'Body=Brooklyn's in the house!' \
-u [AccountSid]:[AuthToken]
```

Hope that helps.